# Compile with VC++

Tags: visual-c++, mingw, invocation-api

I need to convert this gcc build command to VC++

```
g++ -o launcher.exe launcher.cpp -I C:/JDK/include_jdk -I C:/JDK/include_jdk/win32 -L C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client  -ljvm
```

I don't use VC++ at all (use mingw) and just have to compile this single file. Please, help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To compile a single file easily in VC++, open up a Visual Studio Command Prompt (you should have a shortcut installed as part of the installation process), and do the following:

```
cl launcher.cpp
```

That will build `launcher.exe` for you.

To add specific include paths use the `/I` option, and to add linker options, you can add them after passing the `/link` parameter, so for example use `/libpath` to add a library search path, and then just stick the library names onto the command line:

```
cl launcher.cpp /I C:/JDK/include_jdk /I C:/JDK/include_jdk/win32 /link /libpath "C:/Program Files (x86)/Java/jre6/bin/client" libjvm.lib
```

The output filename, if you're compiling a single .cpp file, will be that filename with a `.exe` extension, but that's what you seem to want.  Otherwise, stick a `/out` parameter on... but I'll leave that as an exercise for you.

More information can be found [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f35ctcxw.aspx).